# Only plain text was shown when creating an HTML DOM element with appendChild() and createElement()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I made some code using the javascript `createElement()` and `appendChild()`, but it does not work. However, when I apply jQuery approach, it works normally. Can any one tell me why?

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function foo1(){
      var test_btn = document.createElement("button").appendChild(document.createTextNode("test_btn"));
      document.getElementById("WhyThisNothing").appendChild(test_btn);
    }
    function foo2(){
      $('#WhyThisNothing').append('<button>test_btn</button>');
    }
    function foo3(){
      $('#WhyThisNothing').append($('<button></button>',{text:"test_btn"}));
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="foo1()" id="btn">Click me then error 1:(</button>
    <button onclick="foo2()" id="btn">Click me then ok 2:(</button>
    <button onclick="foo3()" id="btn">Click me then ok 3:(</button>
    <div id="WhyThisNothing"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: appendChild returns the child being attached.  the test_btn var is actually the text node and not the button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`appendChild` returns the appended child, not the parent it was appended to.

So, you have to append the text to the element separately, not chain it, as all you're left with is the textnode

```
function foo1(){
  var test_btn = document.createElement("button");

  test_btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("test_btn"));

  document.getElementById("WhyThisNothing").appendChild(test_btn);
}
```

Comment: Another stupid question is can i do chain like that except using jquery?

Comment: Sure, with jQuery you can chain *(almost)* anything